# how to make cxf-xjc-plugin generate sources in utf-8

Tags: java, maven, encoding, cxf, xjc

I try to generate java classes from xsd in a maven project using cxf-xjc-plugin.

It runs fine, but the generated source files get platform specific encoding (cp1251 on a windows pc) instead of utf-8. If any xsd types contain non-latin characters in schema annotations, then they become readable only in that specific encoding and the compiler later complains with `[WARNING] /C:/.../SomeType.java:[17,4] unmappable character for encoding UTF-8`.

*Please help me force **utf-8** for sources generation.*

The source encoding is set with

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

The build plugin is set up like that:

```
<build>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <extensions>
                <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-dv:2.7.0</extension>
                <extension>net.java.dev.jaxb2-commons:jaxb-fluent-api:2.1.8</extension>
            </extensions>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</sourceRoot>
                    <xsdOptions>
                        <xsdOption>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/Policy.xsd</xsd>
                            <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/Policy.xjb</bindingFile>
                            <extensionArgs>
                                <extensionArg>-Xdv</extensionArg>
                                <extensionArg>-Xfluent-api</extensionArg>
                            </extensionArgs>
                        </xsdOption>
                    </xsdOptions>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
...
```

after having read through some older issues with xjc, particularly [CXF-4369](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4369) and [JAXB-499](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-499) I tried to force encoding with maven project property `<file.encoding>utf-8</file.encoding>` and set a system property while running `mvn -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 clean install`, but got nowhere.

Comment: UPDATE: directly extending `MAVEN_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` allowed generation of source files with proper UTF-8 encoding, but turned the output of unit tests to garbage (because windows console is not really utf-8). I'm sure there is a proper way to force the plugin respect source encoding without enforcing changing platform encoding for other components.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I could make cxf-xjc-plugin generate sources in UTF-8 by adding the following entry to the xsdOption element:

```xml
<extensionArgs>
    <arg>-encoding</arg>
    <arg>UTF-8</arg>
</extensionArgs>
```

Comment: did not help with  `xjc.getOptions().parseArgument( new String[] { "-encoding" , "UTF-8" } , 0 )` using *jaxb-xjc-2.3.5.jar*

Comment: For those who need to configure it within `build.gradle` the equivalent form in XJC task call is
`xjc(destdir: sourcesDir) {schema(...) arg(value: "-wsdl") arg(value: "-encoding") arg(value: "UTF-8") produces(...)}`

Answer (score 0):

using JVM param `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` did the trick which is a bit heavy, but fine for us :-/