# When generating java classes from xsd, how can I get normal Russian letters?

Tags: java, xsd, cxf, xjc

When generating Java classes from xsd, how can I get normal Russian letters?

In generated Java code I got for example:

```
@XmlType(name = "\u0412\u0438\u0434\u0417\u0430\u043f\u0422\u0438\u043f")
```

But I would like to get:

```
@XmlType(name = "ВидЗапТип")
```

Comment: Have you tried to set you source file encoding to utf8? If you are using something like Maven, it can be done in your project settings.

Comment: Are you using the `xjc` tool or the `jaxb2-maven-plugin`?

Comment: я передаю кодировку UTF-8, я использую maven плагин cxf-xjc-plugin

Comment: I don't understand Russian, please comment in English.

Comment: See [how to make cxf-xjc-plugin generate sources in utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22777386/how-to-make-cxf-xjc-plugin-generate-sources-in-utf-8).

Comment: sorry))). I pass the UTF-8 encoding, I use the maven plugin cxf-xjc-plugin