# gradle wsimport

Tags: gradle, wsimport

I'm running wsimport from my commandline to generate java classes from WSDL as below.

```
wsimport -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all 
         -J-D-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all 
         -b http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd 
         -b customization.xjb 
         -s genSrc https://example.com/XYZ.asmx?wsdl
```

I want to create the equivalent gradle task. 
I shouldn't be using any random custom gradle plugins due to company restrictions. 
What's the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 7):

As @lunicon mention, you should use an ant task, here are some improvements since gradle has change a couple of properties.

```
configurations {
    jaxws
}

dependencies {
    jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
}

task wsimport {
    ext.destDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/generated")
    doLast {
        ant {
            sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.inits()
            destDir.mkdirs()
            taskdef(name: 'wsimport',
                    classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
                    classpath: configurations.jaxws.asPath
            )
            wsimport(keep: true,
                    sourcedestdir: 'src/main/java',
                    package: "com.example.client.api",
                    wsdl: 'src/main/resources/api.wsdl') {
                xjcarg(value: "-XautoNameResolution")
            }
        }
    }
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn wsimport
    source wsimport.destDir
}
```

Comment: [List of wsimport task attributes](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/doc/user-guide/ch04.html#section-925990378001543) (I was looking for encoding in similar way as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27156081/653539)  )

Answer (score 4):

Found on web [use ant task](https://gist.github.com/ae6rt/8883335)
more detail on [metro project site](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/doc/user-guide/ch04.html#using-wsimport-task)

```
configurations {
    jaxws
}

dependencies {
    jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
}

task wsimport {
    ext.destDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/generated")
    doLast {
        ant {
            sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.mkdirs()
            destDir.mkdirs()
            taskdef(name: 'wsimport',
                    classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
                    classpath: configurations.jaxws.asPath
            )
            wsimport(keep: true,
                    destdir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
                    sourcedestdir: destDir,
                    extension: "true",
                    verbose: "false",
                    quiet: "false",
                    package: "com.example.client.api",
                    xnocompile: "true",
                    wsdl: 'src/main/resources/api.wsdl') {
                xjcarg(value: "-XautoNameResolution")
            }
        }
    }
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn wsimport
    source wsimport.destDir
}
```

Comment: There is a cleaner option without ant, just call WsImport class directly as gradle java task, see my answer on similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61090230/6451286

Answer (score 1):

This is the equivalent in Kotlin DSL

```
dependencies {
    jaxws("com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.3.5")
    jaxws("jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:2.3.3")
    jaxws("jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.0")
    jaxws("jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3")
}

tasks.register("wsimport") {
    val destDir by extra("${buildDir}/generated/main/java")

    doLast {
        ant.withGroovyBuilder {
            mkdir(destDir)
            "taskdef"(
                "name" to "wsimport",
                "classname" to "com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport",
                "classpath" to configurations["jaxws"].asPath
            )
            "wsimport"(
                "keep" to true,
                "sourcedestdir" to destDir,
                "wsdl" to "${projectDir}/some-api.wsdl",
                "verbose" to true
            ) {
                "xjcarg"("value" to "-XautoNameResolution")
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.compileJava {
    dependsOn(tasks["wsimport"])
    val destDir: String by tasks["wsimport"].extra
    source(destDir)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
configurations {
    jaxws
}

dependencies {
    jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
}

task wsimport {
    ext.destDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/generated")
    doLast {
        ant {
            destDir.mkdirs()
            taskdef(name: 'wsimport',
                    classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
                    classpath: configurations.jaxws.asPath
            )
            wsimport(keep: true,
                    destdir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
                    sourcedestdir: destDir,
                    extension: "true",
                    verbose: "false",
                    quiet: "false",
                    package: "com.example.client.api",
                    xnocompile: "true",
                    wsdl: 'c:/projects/gluecode/src/main/resources/api.wsdl') {
                xjcarg(value: "-XautoNameResolution")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example copied from another answer of this question but removed one line as "sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.mkdirs()" and added the absolute path of .wsdl

To run the task form gradle follow the below process.

1. Goto run configuration and create new configuration.
2. From the configuration select either Gradle Project or Gradle Task from the list side
   [image: As shown in the below screenshot]

3. task name should same as task <<Task_Name>> {} provided in the .gradle file.
4. From the run configuration run the task then check the console log. In the console log some of the dependencies downloaded from the gradle repository.