# generating classes from wsdl in java 11

Tags: java, gradle, wsdl, java-11

How to generate classes from WSDL in java 11 using gradle 5?

I was using wsimport seeber plugin, but it looks like it doesn't work in java 11

```
dependencies {
            classpath "gradle.plugin.me.seeber.gradle:gradle-wsimport-plugin:1.1.1"
}
```

In Intelij Idea I'm getting:

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':ReturnRedirectWorker-api'.
>
>   > Exception thrown while executing model rule: WsimportPlugin.PluginRules#createWsdlSourceSets(ModelMap,
>   >     FileOperations) > create(wsdlMain) > create(wsdl)
>   >     Could not create LanguageSourceSet of type WsdlSourceSet

Answer (score 8):

Wsinport and wsgen tools were removed from Java 11 - [JEP 320](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320), but they can be found in [Metro JAX-WS](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/) which is now part of [EE4J initiative](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws).

Command line tool like `wsimport` was nothing else but wrapper around calling  Java class `com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport`. This class is included in Metro JAX-WS (available in maven artifacts [**jaxws-rt**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2-1) or [**jaxws-tools**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-tools) or others)

**Classes can be generated directly from Java**:

```java
// SomeClass.java
String[] args = new String[]{
    "-target", "2.1",
    "-s", "src/main/java",
    "-keep",
    "-Xnocompile",
    "-extension",
    "-encoding", "UTF-8",
    "-wsdllocation", "http://localhost/wsdl",
    "src/main/resources/META-INF/SomeService.wsdl"
};
com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport.main(args);
```

**Or can be generated easily by gradle task**:

```
// build.gradle
task wsImport(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = "com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport"
    args "-target", "2.1",
        "-s", "src/main/java",
        "-keep",
        "-Xnocompile",
        "-extension",
        "-encoding", "UTF-8",
        "-wsdllocation", "http://localhost/wsdl",
        "src/main/resources/META-INF/SomeService.wsdl"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.3.2-1'
}
```

Tested in Java 13 and Gradle 6.

The best part is, there are no extra plugins or fancy dependencies, except for 'original' one.

Comment: the problem I have with this approach is that when I want to run generation before compiling (as my code dependsOn the generated one) I add :
`compileJava.dependsOn wsimportCovercard`
and I get: 
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:classes
\--- :compileJava
     \--- :wsimport
          \--- :classes (*)

Comment: A couple of tweaks:
1. You need `jaxws-tools`, not `jaxws-rt`, as a dependency.
2. It's better to create a separate configuration for your task, declare the dependency there, and not clutter your app's classpath: `configurations { wsImport } ... task wsImport(type: JavaExec) { classpath configurations.wsImport.files ...}`

Comment: You can find wsimport syntax here: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/metro-jax-ws/3.0.0/docs/ch04.html#wsimport-syntax

Comment: Shouldn't gradle tasks define their inputs and outputs? How would you do that with wsimport? Does the JavaExec task somehow automatically take care of that for you?

Comment: in gradle dependencies, add: 
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.1.4'
}

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a new plugin for Gradle [wsdl2java](https://github.com/bjornvester/wsdl2java-gradle-plugin). It is simple to use and configure you just need to add plugin:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.github.bjornvester.wsdl2java' version '1.2'
}

...

wsdl2java {
    includes = ['wsdl/test.wsdl']
}
```